# How do I prove this formula with LeviCivitaTensor?

Tags: tensors

How do I prove that

$$ \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{ijm}=2\delta_k^m ? $$

If I use

```
TensorContract[ TensorProduct[LeviCivitaTensor[3, List],LeviCivitaTensor[3, List]], {1,2}]
```

I get zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself:

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[LeviCivitaTensor[3, List], 
LeviCivitaTensor[3, List]], {{1, 4}, {2, 5}}]
```

> {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}